# Método que usa um valor aleatório como parâmetro para trocar os caracteres de uma string

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

Tenho esse código que está funcionando perfeitamente, mas eu preciso que no lugar do X apareçam valores aleatórios. Quero que o resultado retornado seja composto por letras aleatórias e que a posição de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas seja obedecida de acordo com a entrada do usuário na função no momento dos testes. Uso essa função para "embaralhar" o nome de pessoas. O primeiro nome é preservado e quero que o restante do nome apareça com caracteres aleatórios.

Exemplo:

- Entrada:

> Pedro Souza

- Resultado

> Pedro Fscet

A quantidade de letras deve permanecer igual e deve ser case sensitive.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Estou usando o SQL DEVELOPER.

```
create or replace FUNCTION EMBARALHA_NOME (NOME IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
primeiro_Nome VARCHAR2(100);
embaralha VARCHAR2(100);
nome_Cortado VARCHAR2(100);
nome_Embaralhado VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
if (NOME is NULL) then
    nome_Embaralhado := NULL; 
  else 
    primeiro_Nome := NVL(SUBSTR(NOME, 0, INSTR(NOME, ' ')-1), NOME);
    nome_Cortado := LTRIM(NOME, primeiro_Nome);
    embaralha := REGEXP_REPLACE(nome_Cortado, '[A-Za-z]', 'x');
    nome_Embaralhado := CONCAT(primeiro_Nome, embaralha);
end if;
return nome_Embaralhado;
END EMBARALHA_NOME;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace FUNCTION EMBARALHA_NOME (NOME IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
primeiro_Nome VARCHAR2(100);
embaralha VARCHAR2(100);
nome_Cortado VARCHAR2(100);
nome_Embaralhado VARCHAR2(100);
param_r char(1);
BEGIN
if (NOME is NULL) then
    nome_Embaralhado := NULL; 
  else 
    primeiro_Nome := NVL(SUBSTR(NOME, 0, INSTR(NOME, ' ')-1), NOME);
    nome_Cortado := LTRIM(NOME, primeiro_Nome);
    for i in 1..length(nome_Cortado)
    loop
      if substr(nome_Cortado,i,1) <> ' ' then
        --https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_random.htm#TTPLP71246
        if substr(nome_Cortado,i,1) = upper(substr(nome_Cortado,i,1)) then
          param_r := 'U';
        else
          param_r := 'l';
        end if;
        nome_Embaralhado := nome_Embaralhado || dbms_random.string(param_r,1);
      else
        nome_Embaralhado := nome_Embaralhado || ' ';
      end if;
    end loop;
end if;
--return nome_Embaralhado;
nome_Embaralhado := primeiro_Nome || nome_Embaralhado;
END EMBARALHA_NOME;
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era exatamente isso que eu precisava fazer. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Até guardei , pois pode ser útil em criação de bds de teste

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o pacote DBMS_RANDOM do Oracle para gerar valores aleatórios. Além de números, ele também gera strings.

Para gerar uma string com uma quantidade `n` de caracteres, utilize a seguinte sintaxe: **SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('L', n) FROM DUAL**.

Substitua `n` por um número inteiro, i.e.:

```
SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('L', 8) FROM DUAL
-- vai resultar em algo como 'flawifka'
```

O `'L'` no código se refere a *lowercase* (somente caracteres minúsculos). Você pode substituir por:

- `'U'` para somente caracteres maiúsculos;
- `'A'` para caracteres maiúsculos e minúsculos;
- `'X'` para números e letras, mas todas as letras serão maiúsculas (não sei porque);
- `'P'` para todo e qualquer caractere que possa ser impresso.

Comment: Mas dessa forma eu não vou conseguir definir o tamanho do resultado de acordo com o tamanho do nome, né? E nem vai seguir a ordem das letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, correto?

Comment: @LucasVinícius Você pode usar `LENGTH(NOME)` como o valor inteiro. Já para garantir uma primeira letra maiúscula e o restante minúsculo, basta invocar a função de geração aleatória duas vezes: uma com formato `'U'` e tamanho 1, a outra com formato `'L'` e tamanho `LENGTH(NOME) - 1`.

Comment: Como fica a declaração dessa função duas vezes? Declara tudo de uma vez só na mesma linha?

Comment: E se tiver um nome dessa forma: Pedro Sousa F da Silva